# Differentiating between user scroll and programatic page change in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a `android.support.v4.view.ViewPager` in my application and I would like to differentiate between a programmatically-initiated smooth scroll and a user-initiated touch scroll.

I've had a look at `ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener` and I believe that the answer may lie in there but I'm just not sure how.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

OK, so it turns out that I was right about the answer lying in `ViewPager.onPageChangeListener`. In particular it lies in using `onPageScrollStateChanged(int state)`. Essentially there are three states that a page in a `ViewPager` can be in:

1. Dragging: Indicates that the pager is currently being dragged by the user.
2. Idle: Indicates that the pager is in an idle, settled state.
3. Settling: Indicates that the pager is in the process of settling to a final position.

So the dragging state only occurs when the current page is being physically dragged by the user. Thus when the user has swiped a page the states occur in the following order: Dragging -> Settling -> Idle. Now, the `onPageSelected(int position)` method is called between the "Settling" and "Idle" states. Thus, in order to determine whether or not a page change was caused by a user scroll one just needs to check that the previous state was "dragging" and that the current state is "Settling". You can then keep a `boolean` variable to track whether or not the page change was user initiated or not and check it in your `onPageSelected(int position)` method.

Here is my `onPageScrollStateChanged` method

```
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) 
{
    if (previousState == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING
            && state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING)
        userScrollChange = true;

    else if (previousState == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING
            && state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE)
        userScrollChange = false;

    previousState = state;
}
```

The `if` and `else if` statements need not be so explicit but I did so for clarity.

Comment: Still a good answer in 2016. In fact I'm going to make this into an abstract base class with a `wasUserScroll()` method for all to use. :)

Comment: what initial value should I set for `previousState` variable?

Comment: If the user is dragging and programmatically invoke setCurrentItem, ```userScrollChange``` will be true.

Answer (score 7):

I have based myself on the answer mark as correct and in the comments below.

First I analyze how the complete listener behave:

```
USER
onPageScrollStateChanged:        1             SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING
onPageScrollStateChanged:        2             SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING
onPageSelected:              SELECTION     
onPageScrollStateChanged:        0             SCROLL_STATE_IDLE

PROGRAMATIC
onPageScrollStateChanged:        2             SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING
onPageSelected:              SELECTION
onPageScrollStateChanged:        0             SCROLL_STATE_IDLE
```

#### Findings:

- As you can see in both cases the events end when the `onPageScrollStateChanged` move to `SCROLL_STATE_IDLE`, **this means idle is the end of the cycle**
- The user event is `SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING` and then `SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING` **which are 2 `states` different than only 1 `state` for the programmatic event** `SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING`
- `onPageSelected` happens before the end of the cycle, but after we are able to determinate if the change was triggered by the user or programmatically, **so whatever happened before will tell us in that point if it was the user or not**

#### Solution:

So I use a `List<Integer>` that is reset every time the cycle ends, and to be able to know if the user triggered the event in the `onPageSelected` method I check the size of the `List`. **If the size is 2 that means the user scroll the pager.**

```
abstract class PagerListenerActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {

    private static final int USER_SCROLL = 2;
    private List<Integer> validator = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        if (validator.size() == USER_SCROLL) {
            userScroll(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        validator.add(state);
        if (ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE == state) {
            validator.clear();
        }

    }

    protected abstract void userScroll(int position);
}
```

Now, this class can conveniently be inherited by another that need it.

Answer (score 4):

You are right about using `ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener`:

```
@Override
public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
    // programmatically-initiated                           
}

@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {

}

@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
    // user-initiated touch scroll      
}
```

Alternatively, you can use boolean flags to differentiate between `programmatically-initiated smooth scroll and a user-initiated touch scroll`. For example, if you use `setCurrentItem(int item)` to programmatically change the page, try:

```
boolean progChange = false;

....
....
....

progChange = true;
setCurrentItem(somePageId);     // Set progChange = true every time

....
....
....
```

Inside your `ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener`:

```
@Override
public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {

}

@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
    if (progChange) {
        // programmatically-initiated
    } else {
        // user-initiated touch scroll
    }

    // Set progChange to false;
    progChange = false;                 
}

@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin extension functions:

```
interface OnPageChangeWithUserInfoListener {
    fun onPageScrolled(
        position: Int,
        positionOffset: Float,
        positionOffsetPixels: Int
    )

    fun onPageSelected(
        position: Int,
        userInitiated: Boolean // New parameter!
    )

    fun onPageScrollStateChanged(state: Int)
}

fun ViewPager.setOnPageChangeListenerWithUserInfo(onPageChangeWithUserInfoListener: OnPageChangeWithUserInfoListener) {
    var previousState: Int = -1
    var userScrollChange = false

    addOnPageChangeListener(object : ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
        override fun onPageScrolled(
            position: Int,
            positionOffset: Float,
            positionOffsetPixels: Int
        ) {
            onPageChangeWithUserInfoListener.onPageScrolled(position, positionOffset, positionOffsetPixels)
        }

        override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
            onPageChangeWithUserInfoListener.onPageSelected(position, userScrollChange)
        }

        override fun onPageScrollStateChanged(state: Int) {
            if (previousState == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING &&
                state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING) {
                userScrollChange = true
            } else if (previousState == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING &&
                state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                userScrollChange = false
            }

            previousState = state

            onPageChangeWithUserInfoListener.onPageScrollStateChanged(state)
        }
    })
}
```