# Determine user scroll and programmatic scroll page change in android ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a `android.support.v4.view.ViewPager` in my application and i have implemented `TimerTask` to auto scroll the pages and using a custom Scroller to reduce the page transition animation time. I'm trying to stop the auto-scrolling when the user manually scrolls the page.

I followed the @Vikram answer from the below SO question but the programmatic scrolling is detected as user scrolling. And **viewPager.OnPageChangeListener** is called several times in a single scroll.

[Differentiating between user scroll and programatic page change in ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17819970/differentiating-between-user-scroll-and-programatic-page-change-in-viewpager)

*Is there any way to reduce the transition speed or differentiate user scrolling and programmatic scrolling in this setup?*

Here's my custom Scroller class

```
public class FixedSpeedScroller extends Scroller {

private int mDuration = 1000;

public FixedSpeedScroller(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public FixedSpeedScroller(Context context, Interpolator interpolator) {
    super(context, interpolator);
}

public FixedSpeedScroller(Context context, Interpolator interpolator, boolean flywheel) {
    super(context, interpolator, flywheel);
}


@Override
public void startScroll(int startX, int startY, int dx, int dy, int duration) {
    // Ignore received duration, use fixed one instead
    super.startScroll(startX, startY, dx, dy, mDuration);
}

@Override
public void startScroll(int startX, int startY, int dx, int dy) {
    // Ignore received duration, use fixed one instead
    super.startScroll(startX, startY, dx, dy, mDuration);
}}
```

Here's my viewPager setup

```
public void setUpViewPager() {

    mIndicator = (PageIndicatorView) findViewById(R.id.pivGroupFlyer);
    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.vpGroupFlyer);
    mPager.setAdapter(new GroupFlyerAdapter(this, mFlyerList));

    Field mScroller = null;
    try {
        mScroller = ViewPager.class.getDeclaredField("mScroller");
        mScroller.setAccessible(true);

        FixedSpeedScroller scroller = new FixedSpeedScroller(mPager.getContext(), new DecelerateInterpolator());
        mScroller.set(mPager, scroller);

    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mIndicator.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mIndicator.setAnimationType(AnimationType.WORM);
    mIndicator.setRadius(2);
    mIndicator.setViewPager(mPager);

    // Auto start of viewpager
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final Runnable Update = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if (currentPage == mFlyerList.size()) {
                currentPage = 0;
                progChange = true;
            }
            progChange = true;
            mPager.setCurrentItem(currentPage++, true);
        }
    };
    final Timer swipeTimer = new Timer();
    swipeTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(Update);
        }
    }, 4000, 5000);

    if (!(mFlyerList.size() == 0)) {
        mGroupHeader.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    mPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            if(positionOffsetPixels == 0 ){

            } else {
                if(progChange) {
                    //programmatically-initiated
                    Log.e("APP", "SCROLL");
                } else {
                    //user-initiated touch scroll
                    Log.e("USER", "SCROLL");
                    swipeTimer.cancel();
                }
                progChange = false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Use AutoScrollViewPager instead of normal ViewPager....https://github.com/Trinea/android-auto-scroll-view-pager
https://github.com/demoNo/AutoScrollViewPager
https://github.com/fccaikai/AutoScrollViewPager

Comment: i don't want to use any 3rd party libs in my project

Comment: you can customize that code according to your use and can make like your own.

Comment: let me check on that

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem.
solve simply by add a boolean var:
`var isProgramScroll=false`
when scroll by code: add line
`isProgramScroll=true`
on listener:

```
if (isProgramScroll) {
  isProgramScroll=false;
  ...
} else {
  ...
}
```